# NetSuite InvDetail Bin and Serial number ID's keep changing

Tags: netsuite

Ok, this I'm having a very weird issue. On different transactions or different Items the field ID's for "SERIAL/LOT NUMBER" and "BIN" fields seem to keep changing.
I would have assumed that:
BIN == 'binnumber'
SERIAL/LOT NUMBER == 'issueinventorynumber' || 'receiptinventorynumber'

However this dose not seem to be the case. I just had a MAP/REDUCE create a IA and the only way I was able to make it without getting errors was by using **'issueinventorynumber' to set value to ITEMS that use only BIN and 'receiptinventorynumber' to set value to ITEM that have only SERIAL/LOT NUMBER.**

I don't understand the logic here. **How is 'binnumber' not the field id for the BIN field?** Why do they change from Transaction to transaction or Item to Item.
*(meaning not why are some bin numbered and some serial/lot number. my question is why the field ID's are not consistent and how do I know what they will be when)*

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it has to do with if the qty is > 0 or < 0.
If the line.qty its smaller then zero id == 'receiptinventorynumber' ELSE 'issueinventorynumber'